# Make .ISO of bootable thumbdrive in Windows

Tags: windows, iso, bootable

I'm looking for a free App that can make .ISO images of any partition, not just optical drives...

Current intention is to make copies of recovery thumbdrives to be stored on a NAS on Windows.